# Does Oracle ADF Mobile/MAF provide any free trial version?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I am new to ADF mobile framework, as I knew it is not free, but I want to have a try whether is this apply to my requirement.

Does it provide any free trial version?

If license needed, where can I see the quotation?

Can I just buy ADF mobile(AMX component) extension license only and apply to ADF essential?

Comment: Most features (maybe all) you need could be included in ADF essentials, which is free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

MAF - as most of oracle products - is license free for development purposes. You will need a licence once you go to production.

Comment: Can I use MAF framework only(no ADF) for my Mobile Design? And structure my own Service endpoint design to communicate with front tier(MAF)? My purpose just want it apply to android and IOS, I have my own backend service

Comment: You don't need ADF for MAF, you can use your own backend services.

Comment: To be clear - you mean ADF *BC* - Business Components. ADF is composed of 4 "parts" _ ADF BC, ADF Model, ADF Controller and ADF Faces. MAF is not considered "Big ADF" since it does not include ADF BC and does not use ADF Faces components. ADF BC components can be exposed as SDO Web Services and accessed as a web service from MAF.